# Pre-select checkBox from database fields in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have a group checkbook list which i want to preselect from the database table. I amusing following code to for the selection of this but it is not working

Data in table is store in following format 
example:-

```
1,2,
1,5,7,
1,2,3,4,
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:checkboxlist id="chkBoxDaysList" runat="server">
 <asp:listitem  runat="server" value="1"  Text="Sunday" />
 <asp:listitem  runat="server" value="2" Text="Monday" />
 <asp:listitem  runat="server" value="3" Text="Tuesday" />
 <asp:listitem  runat="server" value="4" Text="Wednesday" />
 <asp:listitem  runat="server" value="5" Text="Thrusday" />
 <asp:listitem  runat="server" value="6" Text="Friday" />
 <asp:listitem  runat="server" value="7" Text="Saturday" />
</asp:checkboxlist>
```

**C# Code to preselect checkbox based on data saved previously**

public void getSelectedDays()
{
    IDataReader dr;

```
String strSqlDays = "SELECT * FROM EventCalender WHERE rowID = 6";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = DataProvider.Connect_Select(strSqlDays);
dr = ds.Tables[0].CreateDataReader();

string[] s = new string[50];
while (dr.Read())
{
    s = dr["EventDays"].ToString().Split(',');

}
int length = s.Length;
for (int i = 0; i <= s.Length - 1; i++)
{
    string cntry = s[i];
    for (int j = 0; j <= chkBoxDaysList.Items.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        if (chkBoxDaysList.Items[j].Text == s[i])
        {
            chkBoxDaysList.Items[j].Selected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Right now code doesn't generate any error but doesn't select any checkbox also

Comment: I am using following example http://dotnetaid.com/2012/02/16/how-to-show-the-selected-item-in-the-checkboxlist-fetching-from-the-database/

Comment: when you debug your code, does it come to this line 'chkBoxDaysList.Items[j].Selected = true;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking text of checkbox with value from DB. Please check value of the checkboxlist with value from DB record.Corrected code is shown below-->

```
 if (chkBoxDaysList.Items[j].Value == s[i])
        {
            chkBoxDaysList.Items[j].Selected = true;
            break;
        }
```

Comment: I knew i was making some silly mistake.. Appreciate you reply.. For me these kind of mistakes always go un-notice.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from empreg where empid=@empid", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", txtid.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adpt.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                IDataReader dr = ds.Tables[0].CreateDataReader();
                txtfname.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
                txtlname.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
                RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
                txtdob.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();
                txtdoj.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString();
                txtsal.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][6].ToString();
                txtadd.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][7].ToString();
                DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][8].ToString();
                //checkbox1
                string[] b = new string[50];
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    b = dr["Dept"].ToString().Split(',');
                }

                for (int i = 0; i <= b.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    foreach (ListItem item in this.CheckBoxList1.Items)
                        if (item.Value == b[i])
                        {
                            item.Selected = true;
                            i++;
                        }
                }
```